# How to filter data in Column Google Sheets with URL Parameter in Google Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying Google Script and I want to display data based on keyword parameters which will later refer to Column C as a data filter which will be displayed according to what is searched for in the parameter keyword.

For example in my previous project I had a parameter as pagination

`?page=1&limit=10`

well now I have a new problem to solve which is both search and pagination, I have column b as the reference for the search

`?page=1&limit=10&search=San Andreas`

How do I implement the code below?

```
function doGet(e) {
  var page = e.parameter.page || 1;
  var limit = e.parameter.limit || 10;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10S8Igzt1tpqUBgJHVKpny-2s6G3Y3-vFsLMvlZVqpkc/edit#gid=810612111");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("list_film");
  return getUsers(sheet, page, limit); 
}

function getUsers(sheet, page, limit){
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var dataArray = rows.splice(limit * (page - 1), limit).reduce((ar, [a, b, c, d]) => ar.concat({id: a, year: b, title: c, img: d}), []);
  var jo = {};
  jo.user = dataArray;
  var result = JSON.stringify(jo);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(result).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

**Edit:**

I mean column C

**Edit for solved:**

I want to say thank you to @Tanaike who helped me so hard!

Here's my final code

```
function doGet(e) {
 var page = e.parameter.page || 1;
  var limit = e.parameter.limit || 10;
  var search = e.parameter.search || "";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10S8Igzt1tpqUBgJHVKpny-2s6G3Y3-vFsLMvlZVqpkc/edit#gid=810612111");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("list_film");
  return getUsers(sheet, page, limit, search);
}

function getUsers(sheet, page, limit, search){
  var lowCase = search.toString().toLowerCase();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues().filter(([,,c]) => c.toString().toLowerCase().includes(lowCase));
  var dataArray = rows.splice(limit * (page - 1), limit).reduce((ar, [a, b, c, d]) => ar.concat({id: a, year: b, title: c, img: d}), []);
  var jo = {};
  jo.user = dataArray;
  var result = JSON.stringify(jo);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(result).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values from the sheet "list_film" of Spreadsheet `SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10S8Igzt1tpqUBgJHVKpny-2s6G3Y3-vFsLMvlZVqpkc/edit#gid=810612111")`.
- You want to retrieve the values by searching the value of `search` from the column "B".

#### Modification points:

- From `e.parameter.page`, `e.parameter.limit` and `?page=1&limit=10&search=San Andreas` in your script, I understood that you are using Web Apps.
- In this case, it is required to use `San Andreas` of `?page=1&limit=10&search=San Andreas` like `e.parameter.search`.
- I would like to propose to modify `sheet.getDataRange().getValues()` in `getUsers` by adding `filter`. It's like `sheet.getDataRange().getValues().filter(([,b]) => b == search)`

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
  var page = e.parameter.page || 1;
  var limit = e.parameter.limit || 10;
  var search = e.parameter.search || "";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10S8Igzt1tpqUBgJHVKpny-2s6G3Y3-vFsLMvlZVqpkc/edit#gid=810612111");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("list_film");
  return getUsers(sheet, page, limit, search); 
}

function getUsers(sheet, page, limit, search){
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues().filter(([,b]) => b == search);
  var dataArray = rows.splice(limit * (page - 1), limit).reduce((ar, [a, b, c, d]) => ar.concat({id: a, year: b, title: c, img: d}), []);
  var jo = {};
  jo.user = dataArray;
  var result = JSON.stringify(jo);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(result).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

- In this case, when it requests to `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec?page=1&limit=10&search=San Andreas`, `San Andreas` is searched from the column "B" of sheet "list_film" and the rows, which are the same with `San Andreas`, are returned.

  - If you want to retrieve the values including `search`, please use `b.toString().includes(search)` instead of `b == search`.

#### Note:

- **When you modified the script of Web Apps, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to the Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
- Although I'm not sure about the values of column "B", if above script was not the result you expect, please try to modify `sheet.getDataRange().getValues().filter(([,b]) => b == search)` to `sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues().filter(([,b]) => b == search)` and test it again.
- If you want to compare with other column instead of the column "B", for example, when you want to compare the value of `search` with the column "C", please modify `filter(([,b]) => b == search)` to `filter(([,,c]) => c == search)`.

#### References:

- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

### Added:

#### Modification points:

- From your [`my last code`](https://pastebin.com/59XjR44C) as follows, it was found that my suggested script was not correctly used.

  ```
     function doGet(e) {
     var page = e.parameter.page || 1;
      var limit = e.parameter.limit || 10;
      var search = e.parameter.search || "";
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10S8Igzt1tpqUBgJHVKpny-2s6G3Y3-vFsLMvlZVqpkc/edit#gid=810612111");
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("list_film");
      return getUsers(sheet, page, limit, search); 
    }

    function getUsers(sheet, page, limit, search){
      var rows = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues().filter(([,b]) => b == search);
      var rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues().slice(1);
      var rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues().reverse();
      var dataArray = rows.splice(limit * (page - 1), limit).reduce((ar, [a, b, c, d]) => ar.concat({id: a, year: b, title: c, img: d}), []);
      var jo = {};
      jo.user = dataArray;
      var result = JSON.stringify(jo);
      return ContentService.createTextOutput(result).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
    }
  ```
- At `var rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues().slice(1);` and `var rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues().reverse();`, the values are retrieved using `sheet.getDataRange().getValues()`. By this, the values are not filtered. I think that this is the reason of your current issue.

When your current script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function doGet(e) {
 var page = e.parameter.page || 1;
  var limit = e.parameter.limit || 10;
  var search = e.parameter.search || "";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10S8Igzt1tpqUBgJHVKpny-2s6G3Y3-vFsLMvlZVqpkc/edit#gid=810612111");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("list_film");
  return getUsers(sheet, page, limit, search);
}

function getUsers(sheet, page, limit, search){
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues().filter(([,,c]) => c == search);
  var dataArray = rows.splice(limit * (page - 1), limit).reduce((ar, [a, b, c, d]) => ar.concat({id: a, year: b, title: c, img: d}), []);
  var jo = {};
  jo.user = dataArray;
  var result = JSON.stringify(jo);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(result).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

- If you want to remove the 1st header row and return the reversed values, please modify the function `getUsers` as follows.

  ```
    function getUsers(sheet, page, limit, search){
      var rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues().slice(1).filter(([,,c]) => c == search).reverse();
      var dataArray = rows.splice(limit * (page - 1), limit).reduce((ar, [a, b, c, d]) => ar.concat({id: a, year: b, title: c, img: d}), []);
      var jo = {};
      jo.user = dataArray;
      var result = JSON.stringify(jo);
      return ContentService.createTextOutput(result).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
    }
  ```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but the data displayed is the same and does not filter column B data based on keywords in the parameters. I am also still trying to solve this problem but to no avail :(

Comment: @T6VK Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In this case, I would like to confirm your current situation by checking your sample Spreadsheet for replicating your issue. Because in my environment, when I tested the script using a sample Spreadsheet, the returned value can be filtered by the column "B" with `search`. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. I deeply apologize for my poor skill. So can you provide your sample Spreadsheet including your current script for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @T6VK I confirmed that your question had been changed now. I apologize for this. In your 1st question, you wanted to use the column "B" as the search column. But in your updated one, you want to use the column "C". In that case, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I have already written the modification point at 3rd option of "Note" section. If you cannot understand about it, please tell me. If that modification was not the direct solution of your current issue, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @T6VK As an important point, when you modified the script of Web Apps, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to the Web Apps. Please be careful this.

Comment: Thank you too for wanting to reply.
May I know what data appears in your environment?

Previously I apologized for my mistake. Because what I should have written in the question is column C not column B and actually I want to make JSON results based on the keyword in the search parameter, so the data that appears is only those that are similar in keywords and then the filtered data will be paginated. I have also tried your 3rd option and the results are not filtered data based on keywords.

Comment: For example:
I have some values ​​that contain the word "the" in Column C, well I want them to be when I execute
? page = 1 & limit = 10 & search = the

then the data that appears only is similar to what is in the parameters only, I have tried but with no success

Comment: I have updated to the 27th project version. And this is my last code https://pastebin.com/59XjR44C

Comment: @T6VK Thank you for replying. In my environment, I tested the script using the Spreadsheet which has "sample1", "sample2",,, in the column "C". In this case, when `?page=1&limit=10&search=sample1` is used, the row including "sample1" in the column "C" is retrieved.

Comment: @T6VK From your provided current script, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? When you modified the script of Web Apps, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to the Web Apps. Please be careful this.

Comment: Thank you for helping. Your English skills are not bad, I am here who is poor in English skills.

I apologize for slightly changing the script that you have suggested and want to confirm that all the help you wrote above does work when writing keywords that are very similar to the data in Column C, for example "Just Test" But I want the script searching with data similar to keywords, is that possible?

Comment: @T6VK Thank you for replying. Before your new request, can I ask you whether my suggested answer could resolve your question? About your new request of `for example "Just Test" But I want the script searching with data similar to keywords, is that possible?`, if you want to search the value including `"Just Test"` from the column "C", you can achieve it by modifying `c == search` to `c.toString().includes(search)`. But, I think that it cannot search it as "similar". I apologize for this.

Comment: I am very grateful for all your help, everything you suggest can work out well! You are amazing and I learn a lot from you, all my problems have been solved

Comment: @T6VK Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: 2 years later:
Is there a way to user "&search=" in a URL link?
My use case is that I want to show users a filter version of a Google Sheet. For example, a sheet containing activities with client will be filters to show activities with only a specific client, as per the client code.

Comment: @user13708028 About your question of `Is there a way to user "&search=" in a URL link?`, I would like to support you. But, unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. So, can you post it as a new question by including more information? By this, it will help users including me think of the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: @Tanaike - Thanks for your feedback. Sure, no problem. I posted my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74074216/google-sheets-filter-using-url-parameters-as-per-awesome-table